# Last item on the reduce Method

Tags: python, function, reduce

I have this list of countries:

`countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']`

I need to resolve following exersice: Use reduce to concatenate all the countries and to produce this sentence: Estonia, Finland, Sweden, Denmark, Norway, and Iceland are north European countries

```py
def sentece(pais,pais_next):

        if pais_next=='Iceland':
            return pais+' and '+pais_next + ' are north European countries'
        else: return pais+', '+pais_next

countries_reduce=reduce(sentece,countries)
print(countries_reduce)
```

The code run perfect, but if I want to do in general, How I know what is the last element?.

Comment: Can you call `reduce` on all *but* the last county?

Comment: Does the exercise strictly *require* using `reduce`? Because `reduce` is both ugly and inefficient, especially when Python already provides an optimized means of concatenating a set of strings with a common joiner (`str.join`, e.g. `', '.join(seq)`).

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` function doesn't have a way to tell it what to do about the last item, only what to do about the initialization.

There's two general ways to go about it:

1. Just do simple concatenation with a comma and a space, but only on the first `n-1` items of the list, then manually append the correct format for the last item
2. Change the last item from `Iceland` to `and Iceland are north European countries`, then do the concatenation for the full list.

Comment: Sure, I can use another way, but the excersice needs to use Reduce, because I learn about this method and try to solve with that, but It's how you say, It's better with str concatenation or a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out which is the last element is a bad idea; any solution that would give you that information would be a royal hack.

Normally, you wouldn't use `reduce` to solve this at all (repeated concatenation is a form of [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm), involving `O(n²)` work, where efficient algorithms can be `O(n)`), so you'd just use `', '.join`, e.g.:

```
countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']
countries_str = f'{", ".join(countries[:-1])} and {countries[-1]} are north European countries'
```

or, premodifying `countries[-1]` to reduce the complexity to the point where an f-string isn't necessary (assuming an Oxford comma is okay):

```
countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']
countries[-1] = 'and ' + countries[-1]  # Put the "and " prefix in front ahead of time
countries_str = ', '.join(countries) + ' are north European countries'
```

where `join` is used for the consistent join components, wrapped in an f-string that inserts the last item along with the rest of the formatting.

If you *must* use `reduce`, you'd still want to handle the final element separately, either by processing it completely separately at the end, e.g.

```
from functools import reduce

countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']
countries_str = f'{reduce(lambda x, y: f"{x}, {y}", countries[:-1])} and {countries[-1]} are north European countries'
print(countries_str)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BC4JAEIXv/oqhyyrYIboJ3TLo0qWjSGw64pLOyLiiIv52WwuSbh8f896bZrQl03FZCuEaio4yy1y1YOqGxYJg3mXoeRl3ZMVgCydIVNxaJqNVCOpiqNKUr3jvMUda6YxUa3mteGPp9bjSNcPPZbqVPVorrrBQ03fHr3T9zDUMIYwRFLtpmEOYxnkXwi@TRPtDGszgqmDarJPOCQK5t0uIO@EGNW055TViyPp/48GyvAE)

or by manually tweaking it ahead of time so it can be used in a consistent manner (assuming you're okay with the Oxford comma):

```
from functools import reduce

countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']
countries[-1] = 'and ' + countries[-1]  # Put the "and " prefix in front ahead of time
countries_str = f'{reduce(lambda x, y: f"{x}, {y}", countries)} are north European countries'
print(countries_str)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY@xasNAEER7fcWgFGcTpQjpAunigBsTSGlMuEh76LC0J1Z7WELo2xVdUgh3j51hZrYbtQ78sixOQgsXudQQmh6@7YIohKpYUpaVIbKKpx5vOJtDr4G9NQXMh@fGcpXw60YVcaJ34tbKNeEpyM2OiY4l/TkvW9j56fmyBpr1DINH3At4wGdUaE3IkyNHJ@T8AM9Y17LC1mQrBAf1LW2x373KGuvM9D9/19j2p7IYCoyvcPk0zAWmcc6LrXE/wwqB16drHKKEjixvssk68ay7u479svwC)

Again, ***`reduce` is a bad solution to the problem***; `str.join` (using `', '.join`) is a `O(n)` solution (on CPython, it pre-scans the items to join to compute the final length, then preallocates the complete final `str`, and copies each input *exactly* once), where `reduce` is `O(n²)` (and unlike an actual loop using `+=`, it can't even benefit from the CPython reference interpreter's implementation detail that sometimes allows concatenation to mutate in-place, reducing the number of data copies).

Comment: Hii!

Waos! Your answer it's so complete, I going to do with join, sincerely I had forgotten
this method and I don't think about algortimith complexity because is a simple excersice, but I can enchance my code I need to think it. 

Thanks bro... So good your comment.